# How to set custom fontsize for QuickBlox Chat Message

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, message, quickblox

I am new to iOS developing.
Can any one help me to change the font size of message between user
platform - ios
sdk - QuickBlox

Comment: if you are using UILabel then lbl.font = [UIFOnt .... ];

Comment: thanks for the rlp ....but if i want to change it dynamically with a button click

Comment: then you have to set UIButton Target property and in that action method set the UILable property.